# Convertir string moneda a double sin saber el formato

Tags: java

Estoy tratando de pasar un string con valores aleatorios con diferentes formatos de moneda:

```
1,222.50
1.222,50
1222.5
1222,500
1222
```

A un double para poder insertarlo en la base de datos. Hasta ahora tengo el siguiente código:

```
String a1, a2;
a1 = "1.100,50";
a2 = "1,100.50";
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
double number = nf.parse(a1).doubleValue();
double number2 = nf.parse(a2).doubleValue();
System.out.println(number);
System.out.println(number2);
```

Pero este es el resultado que obtengo:

```
1100.5
1.1
```

No me está funcionando con el formato inglés. Traté con la función `Double.parseDouble(a1)` pero tiene problemas con el formato español. Hay alguna manera de pasarlo a Double independientemente del formato que tenga?

Comment: ¿Tus valores siempre van a tener decimales?

Comment: Puede tener o no. Incluso puede tener delimitador de miles o no. Ahí edito la pregunta, gracias por el comentario

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como bien se menciona solo puede existir un separador de decimales, por lo que debes de identificar cuál es y reemplazarlo con punto para que se haga correctamente la conversión a Double.

Nunca me he topado con el problema que representas, pero me dió la curiosidad y desarrollé el siguiente método rápidamente. Verás que siempre te devuelve el separador de decimales con el punto y elimina los separadores de miles.

```
public static String ajustaMoneda(String valor1)
{

    int lastPosComas = -1;
    int lastPosPuntos = -1;

    lastPosComas = valor1.lastIndexOf(",");
    lastPosPuntos = valor1.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (lastPosComas > lastPosPuntos)
    {
        valor1 = valor1.replace(".", "");
        valor1 = valor1.replace(",", ".");

    }
    else
    {
        valor1 = valor1.replace(",", "");
    }


    Double valorDouble = new Double(valor1);
    System.out.println(valorDouble);

    return valor1;
}
```

Con los ejemplos que pusiste el resultado sería:

Valor de **1,222.50: 1222.5**

Valor de **1.222,50: 1222.5**

Valor de **1222.5: 1222.5**

Valor de **1222,500: 1222.5**

Valor de **1222: 1222.0**

Espero que se adapte a tus necesidades.

Saludos!

Comment: Vos sos hijo de Zeus y amigo del Werever! Mil gracias! Funcionó a la perfección

Comment: De nada, un gusto ayudarte. :D